# UML diagram use case condition

Tags: uml, diagram, use-case-diagram

I am creating use-case diagram. I have two actors: user and admin. Admin can check all orders, and user can check only his/her orders.

Should I create two use cases in my UML diagram, or I can use one use case with condition for user actor?

If I can use condition, which symbol must I use? Square brackets or curly brackets?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to attach a constraint to either the connector, the use case or the actor (where it's most appropriate). It could look like this:

[image]

Note that this is an example and contains redundant constraints which should not be done for a real UC.

Comment: so, I must use invariant?

Comment: The stereotype should be `<<invariant>>` in your case, I guess. However, specifying it is optional.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are doing too much as part of your use case analysis.
Use cases are listing what your users (actors) can do and what benefit they get from doing those actions.
Thinking that way, each user/actor will have a set of actions (use cases) that will provide them with a benefit.
In your example, you should have many use cases for each actor, e.g., Admin would be able to create/delete users and provileges (UC1), list all actions from one or many users (UC2) and both would yeild different results.

When you start building your domain and behaviour models, then you will start adding the details of the behaviour.