# How to represent conditional constraints in UML

Tags: constraints, uml, visual-paradigm

I'm trying to create a class diagram with some constraints in Visual Paradigm. As far as I found so far VP doesn't support OCL so I'm looking for "the right way" to represent these constraints.

[image]

What I'm trying to accomplish is:

```
context Product
    inv: articleId.size() > 0 implies productId = articleId
    inv: articleId.size() = 0 implies materialId.size() = 8
    inv: articleId.size() = 0 implies productId = materialId
    inv: articleId.size() > 0 implies gtin.size() = 13
```

How should I model this in UML?  (And in Visual Paradigm if you might know it?)

Answer (score 0):

You would just need to enclose the constraints in `{ braces }` within the comment and you're done. OCL or plain text is merely a question of taste if you don't have an OCL compiler.

See also [my example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49692740/uml-diagram-use-case-condition).