# UML-Modeling Different User Classes (Actors) in Use Case Diagrams

Tags: web-applications, uml, use-case

I'm building a web application with CRUD/social-network-like functionalities. The problem is that users won't be getting the same privileges when it comes to accessing certain pages nor in terms of services and this apparently should not figure in a use case diagram as an actor needs to be treated independently from the system. A commenter suggested using constraints to check if a user has privilege or not but the problem is that most of time the application won't even do a check, rather will load a different version of the page or will simply not display a command for a certain function. This is my initial take on the problem : [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ME4vs.png), [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LYbUi.png), [3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HH0Yc.png), [4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ze8NK.png).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Generalization is a way to approach this. You can further add constraints as shown in my example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49692740/uml-diagram-use-case-condition).

Please note that `Login` is no use case. A use case is about added value, not about functions. If y login is required you attach a constraint to where it applies (can be an actor or a specific use case; if all except one needs login you can add a general requirement and make a "negative" constraint like `{ no login required }`). As always I recommend to read Bittner/Spence about synthesizing use cases.

Comment: +Thomas Thanks for replying but what if one constraint is assumed for an entire diagram like for diagram 2? I refered to the actor as "Registered User", is that a valid representation? I read many times that the actor, in a use case diagram, should be independent from system representations (aka roles given by the system itself).

Comment: As suggested just place a single constraint on the diagram explaining that it applies generally. As long as you are not interfacing with automata but humans such an approach is valid. Only when you try to generate code/automatic testing/etc. you need to make explicit relations.